# Tengo un error dice que no adivina el nombre del factory

Tags: php, laravel

Hola amigos tengo un error en laravel y ya e visto varios tutoriales y realemente creo que tengo el factory como es:

Factory:

```
<?php
namespace Database\Factories;
use App\Models\categorias;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
class CategoriaFactory extends Factory
{
      public function definition()
    {
      
        return [
            'nombre' => $this->faker->name(),
        ];
       
    }
 }
```

Seeder:

```
<?php
namespace Database\Seeders;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class CategoriasSeeder extends Seeder
{
     public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Categorias::factory(10)->create();
    }
}
```

Modelo:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Categorias extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['nombre'];
}
```

Error:

> Class "Database\Factories\CategoriasFactory" not found
>
> at
> C:\xampp\htdocs\OpperWeb\Servidor\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php:737
> 733▕     public static function factoryForModel(string $modelName)
> 734▕     {
> 735▕         $factory = static::resolveFactoryName($modelName);
> 736▕   ➜ 737▕         return $factory::new();
> 738▕     }
> 739▕
> 740▕     /**
> 741▕      * Specify the callback that should be invoked to guess factory names based on dynamic relationship names.

Comment: `class CategoriaFactory` y el error dice `Factories\CategoriasFactory" not found`... en que quedamos?  es con *s* o sin *s*?

Comment: Me robaste el comentario master

Comment: @Excorpion Soy el más rapido de este lado del Mississipi, lo siento :-D

Comment: asjdjsadjasja  no puedo creer enserio eso, llevo como 4 horas peleando con eso

Comment: @AndredGarciaMartin eso es porque ahora llevo las gafas de cerca, y así lo veo todo, hasta las `s` más escondidas que existen :-)

Comment: Una pregunta ustedes saben como crear un faker dependiendo de una llave foranea o sea que escoja solo numeros que existan en otra tabla?

Comment: pos yo no, lo siento, no se ni que es un faker (pero si lo pronuncio tal cual me suena a insulto en inglés :-))... no se laravel, lo siento, solo soy un [rompetechos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rompetechos) :-)

Comment: Un faker no es el que crea datos falsos para la BD ?? creo solamente haber usado 1, una sola vez, asi que tampoco se mas que tu...